# Ideal website navigation design

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, navigation

I am designing a website and I want to have a static menu at the top and I want to load the corresponding page that the user asks for below the menu. But I don't want to reload the whole page, just the section below the menu should be loaded. What is the ideal design to do that?

Comment: what I am asking is actually is implemented in this very page we are looking at - the logo(stack over flow) and the menus - Questions, tags, users, badges.. they don't seem to load when we click on the menu. Only the page section below is loaded.. my question is how to do that.

Comment: the page does completely reload. You just don't see it because you're at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, applying it to a DIV that covers all you want to replace, although doing that instead of regular pages has a number of disadvantages:

- Search engines can't get to each page
- Users with js off won't be able to browse the site
- You don't really gain much since you are still loading almost the whole page

Comment: The search engine issue can be resolved by using [hash-bangs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html). Gawker recently switched their sites to use hash-bang URLs with their content loaded asynchronously via javascript without losing their SEO ranking. However, they've also taken some [heat](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) for that decision.

Comment: is your suggestion to use includes for the header and menu jsps in every pages and load the whole page and have the menu links point to individual jsps(with the menu and header includes)?

Comment: @Kevin thanks for that link, it looks interesting!
@Jerry I think that's exactly what I'm suggesting, though I don't really know much about jsp so I can't be 100% sure. The idea is, like you say, to have separate pages with some common things like the menu, etc. as includes.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX

http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp

Asynchronous Javascript and XML, uses XML to communicate the request and response objects, can be HTML since HTML is a subset of XML.

Comment: Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for but sounds right to me.  You could alternatively look into using some sort of RIA technology (the one I commonly use is Flex but there are others like Pivot or Google Web Toolkit), which employ the static navigation and aren't necessarily "page" based (this can be an issue when it comes to "deep-linking" something to be wary of depending on your situation)

Comment: @shaunhusain - what I am asking is actually is implemented in this very page we are looking at - the logo(stack over flow) and the menus - Questions, tags, users, badges.. they don't seem to load when we click on the menu. Only the page below is loaded.. my question is how to do that.

Comment: @Jerry - I don't believe this is actually how stackoverflow handles it, I'm pretty sure it just requests the entire page, but AJAX is the simple answer to the question.  The other answers here are AJAX built into something else you can just use without writing your own code but so far as I can tell they all involve the answer you can use AJAX to do this.  AJAX is nothing more than some javascript that makes a request via a special XML request object provided by browsers, in the response handler you can use innerHTML of the DOM element (get by id) to replace the page contents.

Comment: @Jerry there is no such thing in Stackoverflow. They do use AJAX, though, for other purposes, but nothing like loading (almost) the entire page. May I suggest using tools like Firebug (on Firefox) to see things like requests (it shows regular and ajax requests, and a bunch of other useful stuff)

Comment: @Jerry - One more and I'm out of feedback, you can create a .js file that contains all the code that is used for the navigation and use a reference to the script in each HTML file, this way the js is cached and the individual HTML pages load... really any of these are options it all depends on what technologies you want to employ and/or have available, and/or have knowledge of/are willing to learn, and what the specific desired effect is (you could go 90s and frame it up though I don't suggest it).  @cambraca thanks for verifying, also cool hair and interesting music :) Have a good one.

Comment: @shaunhusain and @others - thanks for all the inputs. I tried including the pages in each page and it works good for me. I just highlight the menu item selected in each page that is loaded.